# Make window scroll in Go with GXUI

Tags: scroll, go, scrollbar, gxui

I am trying to add scroll bars to my application windows in Go using GXUI.

Say I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/gxui"
    "github.com/google/gxui/drivers/gl"
    "github.com/google/gxui/samples/flags"
    "github.com/google/gxui/themes/dark"
)

func appMain(driver gxui.Driver) {
    theme := dark.CreateTheme(driver)

    window := theme.CreateWindow(800, 600, "Grid")
    window.SetScale(flags.DefaultScaleFactor)
    window.OnClose(driver.Terminate)

    row := theme.CreateLinearLayout()
    row.SetDirection(gxui.LeftToRight)
    for c := 0; c < 4; c++ {
        col := theme.CreateLinearLayout()
        col.SetDirection(gxui.TopToBottom)
        for r := 0; r < 100; r++ {
            cell := theme.CreateLabel()
            cell.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%d", r*4+c))
            col.AddChild(cell)
        }
        row.AddChild(col)
    }

    window.AddChild(row)
}

func main() {
    gl.StartDriver(appMain)
}
```

When I run it, I get this window:

[image]

How can I get the window to have a scroll bar so that I can view all of the lines?

Comment: You need [ScrollLayout](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gxui#ScrollLayout) I think...

Comment: @AlexKroll , the main problem is to move the display area  together with the square-scroll.

Comment: ScrollLayout seems to be the way, but I'm getting issues with display cutting off.

Comment: @BarryMcNamara ,  changed from 100 to 2000,everything displays as it should.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm that's disappointing. When I change 100 to 2000 it no longer displays properly. I get 0 1 on the first row, 4 5 on the second, and so on down until I hit 664 in the first column and then the second column disappears. The third and fourth columns are gone entirely.

Comment: @BarryMcNamara , that's really strange. For me display so: http://s9.postimg.org/owni8v1hb/image.jpg

Comment: Well at least I know it's not my code. I guess I'll try updating and rebuilding the GXUI packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses ScrollLayout to add a scroll bar to the window. The trick is to make ScrollLayout the window's child and make the next widget (in this case a LinearLayout) a child of the ScrollLayout.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/gxui"
    "github.com/google/gxui/drivers/gl"
    "github.com/google/gxui/samples/flags"
    "github.com/google/gxui/themes/dark"
)

func appMain(driver gxui.Driver) {
    theme := dark.CreateTheme(driver)
    window := theme.CreateWindow(800, 600, "Grid")
    window.SetScale(flags.DefaultScaleFactor)
    window.OnClose(driver.Terminate)
    sl := theme.CreateScrollLayout()
    row := theme.CreateLinearLayout()
    row.SetDirection(gxui.LeftToRight)
    for c := 0; c < 4; c++ {
        col := theme.CreateLinearLayout()
        col.SetDirection(gxui.TopToBottom)
        for r := 0; r < 100; r++ {
            cell := theme.CreateLabel()
            cell.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%d", r*4+c))
            col.AddChild(cell)
        }
        row.AddChild(col)
    }
    sl.SetChild(row)
    window.AddChild(sl)
}

func main() {
    gl.StartDriver(appMain)
}
```

Note that my computer gave me display issues when I increased the number of rows (the rightmost columns began to get cut off), but other people did not encounter this issue, so it is likely due to a bad installation on my end.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to do with help ScrollLayout, but I can propose this variant  on the basis of examples from [github](https://github.com/google/gxui/blob/master/samples/lists/main.go).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/gxui"
    "github.com/google/gxui/drivers/gl"
    "github.com/google/gxui/math"
    "github.com/google/gxui/samples/flags"
    "github.com/google/gxui/themes/dark"
)

type customAdapter struct {
    gxui.AdapterBase
}

func (a *customAdapter) Count() int {
    return 1000
}

func (a *customAdapter) ItemAt(index int) gxui.AdapterItem {
    return index
}

func (a *customAdapter) ItemIndex(item gxui.AdapterItem) int {
    return item.(int)
}

func (a *customAdapter) Size(theme gxui.Theme) math.Size {
    return math.Size{W: 200, H: 25}
}

func (a *customAdapter) Create(theme gxui.Theme, index int) gxui.Control {

    layout1 := theme.CreateLinearLayout()
    layout1.SetDirection(gxui.LeftToRight)
    for c := 0; c < 4; c++ {
        col := theme.CreateLinearLayout()
        col.SetDirection(gxui.TopToBottom)
        cell := theme.CreateLabel()
        cell.SetText(fmt.Sprintf("%d", index*4+c))
        col.AddChild(cell)
        layout1.AddChild(col)
    }
    return layout1
}

func appMain(driver gxui.Driver) {
    theme := dark.CreateTheme(driver)
    window := theme.CreateWindow(600, 400, "Grid")
    window.BorderPen()
    window.SetScale(flags.DefaultScaleFactor)
    window.OnClose(driver.Terminate)
    adapter := &customAdapter{}
    list := theme.CreateList()
    list.SetAdapter(adapter)
    list.SetOrientation(gxui.Vertical)
    window.AddChild(list)
}

func main() {
    gl.StartDriver(appMain)
}
```

Each line is placed in the list,their number and size are specified in the overridden methods.  The advantage is that in the list already have the scrollbar.

Comment: So that mostly works, but the scroll bar is awkwardly in the middle of the screen (an easy fix) and in adding it the rows got changed to some sort of selecting list. This wouldn't really work as a general solution to making any application window scroll.